# selenium-java dependency set in Maven, but Selenium asks for the path to the driver

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I've set `selenium-java` dependency in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But When I run a simple test - I get an exception that the path to the driver is not set: `The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property`

Setting up the Maven dependency isn't it enough for Selenium?
What I'm missing that Selenium can't read Maven dependency?

Answer (score 1):

> Setting up the Maven dependency isn't it enough for Selenium?

No, you need to tell it where to find the web driver in this using something like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", complete_path_to_your_chrome_driver_executable_here);
```

should fix the issue.

You can do a similar configuration in your pom.xml directly by defining a property in the properties section that contains your path and by using systemPropertyVariables in the configuration section of maven-surefire-plugin.

For example:

Create in properties section of your pom.xml

```
<webriver.path>path_to_your_driver_executable</webriver.path>
```

Then add a systemPropertyVariables section in the configuration section of your maven-surefire-plugin

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
   <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webriver.path}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
   [...]
</systemPropertyVariables>
```